# Is there a way to load only previously tagged environments?

Tags: macros, tag

This is a bit complicated, so let me explain what I wondered if it'd be an actual thing.

I have four `.tex` files named *main.tex*, *tex1.tex*, *tex2.tex* and *tex3.tex*.

Now, I'll put a simplified version of my actual files, here they are.

First one:

```
%this is 'tex1'.

\mainenvironment{\mycommand{tag1}{tag2}
Q1 This is a text environment. Here, I put some texts, images, other environments, etc. 
}
    
\mainenvironment{\mycommand{tag2}{tag3}
Q2 This is a text environment. Here, I put some texts, images, other environments, etc. 
}
    
\mainenvironment{\mycommand{tag2}{tag3}
Q3 This is a text environment. Here, I put some texts, images, other environments, etc. 
}
```

Next one:

```
%this is 'tex2'.

\mainenvironment{\mycommand{tag2}{tag3}
Q4 This is a text environment. Here, I put some texts, images, other environments, etc. 
}
    
\mainenvironment{\mycommand{tag1}{tag3}
Q5 This is a text environment. Here, I put some texts, images, other environments, etc. 
}
    
\mainenvironment{\mycommand{tag2}{tag3}
Q6 This is a text environment. Here, I put some texts, images, other environments, etc. 
}
```

And the last one:

```
%this is 'tex3'.

\mainenvironment{\mycommand{tag1}{tag2}
Q7 This is a text environment. Here, I put some texts, images, other environments, etc. 
}
    
\mainenvironment{\mycommand{tag1}{tag3}
Q8 This is a text environment. Here, I put some texts, images, other environments, etc. 
}
    
\mainenvironment{\mycommand{tag1}{tag2}
Q9 This is a text environment. Here, I put some texts, images, other environments, etc. 
}
```

Now, for my `main.tex`, here is how it goes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\mainenvironment}[1]{#1}
\usepackage{import}

\begin{document}

\import{tex/}{tex1.tex}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, I have an empty command called `\mainenvironment`, which I want there for later flexibility (if I want to change the before/after each text block). But that's not the problem. Here's the thing I'm wondering if it's possible.

I'd like to know if one can load **only** some of the *tags* I gave with that `\mycommand` command. For example, after the `\begin{document}`, I'd call some command in order to load only *tag1* from those three files I've created. And then, it'd compile only the text blocks with Q1, Q5, Q7, Q8 and Q9.

I thought that maybe one could change `\mainenvironment` command so it'd be "taggable" and then using something along `\import` to load only tagged textblocks (which are the texts inside the `\mainenvironment` commands), but I couldn't solve this specific puzzle.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You're only talking about a single tag, yet `\mycommand` takes two arguments, both of which seem to be tags. Does your tagging requirement hold for both arguments of `\mycommand`? Also, is there a specific need to use `import`? Why not just `\input`?

Comment: https://ctan.org/pkg/tagging?lang=en may be what you are looking for. The package only allows activating "tag1 OR tag2", not "tag1 AND tag2". If you need the latter, you can use the [modified version that I wrote sometime ago](https://gitlab.msu.edu/wongwil2/www-textools/-/blob/master/Packages/www_tagging.sty).

Answer (score 1):

The following setup does what you need:

[image]

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{tex1.tex}
%this is 'tex1'.

\mainenvironment{\mycommand{tag1}{tag2}
Q1 This is a text environment. Here, I put some texts, images, other environments, etc. 
}
    
\mainenvironment{\mycommand{tag2}{tag3}
Q2 This is a text environment. Here, I put some texts, images, other environments, etc. 
}
    
\mainenvironment{\mycommand{tag2}{tag3}
Q3 This is a text environment. Here, I put some texts, images, other environments, etc. 
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{tex2.tex}
%this is 'tex2'.

\mainenvironment{\mycommand{tag2}{tag3}
Q4 This is a text environment. Here, I put some texts, images, other environments, etc. 
}
    
\mainenvironment{\mycommand{tag1}{tag3}
Q5 This is a text environment. Here, I put some texts, images, other environments, etc. 
}
    
\mainenvironment{\mycommand{tag2}{tag3}
Q6 This is a text environment. Here, I put some texts, images, other environments, etc. 
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{tex3.tex}
%this is 'tex3'.

\mainenvironment{\mycommand{tag1}{tag2}
Q7 This is a text environment. Here, I put some texts, images, other environments, etc. 
}
    
\mainenvironment{\mycommand{tag1}{tag3}
Q8 This is a text environment. Here, I put some texts, images, other environments, etc. 
}
    
\mainenvironment{\mycommand{tag1}{tag2}
Q9 This is a text environment. Here, I put some texts, images, other environments, etc. 
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\approvedtag}[1]{\def\@approvedtag{#1}}% Store approved tag

\newcommand{\mycommand}[2]{%
  % Assumed \mycommand{<tagA>}{<tagB>} is at the beginning of \mainenvironment
  \approvedfalse% Default is to not print anything
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{\@approvedtag}=0
    \approvedtrue% Approved tag in argument #1
  \else
    \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#2}{\@approvedtag}=0
      \approvedtrue% Approved tag in argument #2
    \fi
  \fi
  \ignorespaces
  \ifapproved% Conditionally print remainder of \mainenvironment
}
\newif\ifapproved
\newcommand{\mainenvironment}[1]{%
  #1% Process main environment
  \fi% Close condition
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\approvedtag{tag1}

\input{tex1}

\input{tex2}

\input{tex3}

\end{document}
```

`\approvedtag{<tag>}` allows you to specify the tag you want to be considered as approved.  The solution updates `\mycommand{<tagA>}{<tagB>}` to test whether the approved `<tag>` matches either `<tagA>` or `<tagB>` and then prints the remainder of `\mainenvironment`. Inherently this assumes that content preceding `\mycommand` will *always* be printed and should therefore be the first element within `\mainenvironment`.